# How addAll works with mocked paginated query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have to add the PaginatedQueryList from to secondList which comes from dynamoDbMapper.query for testing. How can I achieve it?

```
List exampleList = secondList.addAll(dynamoDbMapper.query(MyDAOClass.class, queryExpression));
```

I tried to mock the ***PaginatedQueryList*** but am getting **null pointer exception** because elements in mocked **PaginatedQueryList** is empty.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following and it will work:

1. Create mock for paginated result.

   `@Mock
   private PaginatedQueryList<Object> queryResult;`
2. Return mocked result when query is called.

   `when(dynamoDBMapper.query(any(), any())).thenReturn(queryResult);`
3. set result in paginated result by mocking it with an array of expected list, say, firstList.

   `when(queryResult.toArray()).thenReturn(firstList);`
4. Add result in secondList.

   `List exampleList = secondList.addAll(firstlist)`