# How to mock a mapper.query method when the return type is a PaginatedList of items JAVA

Tags: java, junit, mockito, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to test a method that uses DynamoDBMapper to query items from a dyamoDB table.

My method works fine but the problem comes when I'm trying to test.

I'm using Junt4 and Mockito. Basically, I'm just trying to test that my method does its logic with the results fetched from dynamo. In my test, I'm trying to mock those results.

```java
//What I'm trying to mock
mapper.query(DDBProductDocument.class, queryExpression);


//What I have in my test

@MockBean
    PaginatedQueryList paginatedQueryList;


when(mapper.query(
                Mockito.any(),
                Mockito.any()
        )).thenReturn(paginatedQueryList);
```

paginated List should be a list of my mocked results, however, I can't just return my desired mocked results. Has anyone else successfully mocked this? thanks.

Comment: What happens? Error message? Different result? ...?

Comment: It throws a null pointer exception because paginatedList has 0 items. See, I need to create an instance of paginated list having my mocked values, but so far I haven't been able to do that.

Comment: Are you sure you need a PaginatedQueryList? According to the documentation, it is just an implementation of the List interface without additional methods, so you could use any dummy list as return value.

Comment: Nope, it actually needs to return a PaginatedQueryList

Comment: Then maybe you ought to think about the signature of your methods. It is better to program against interfaces than implementations.

Comment: Possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50983169/5524175